# action bar moves app when the keyboard opens

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to code a chatting-app and nearly i'm ready, but there is one thing that let's my hair become grey....
Everytime i open the keyboard to write a message the action bar gets lost to the top. I wan just the messages to go up and the actionbar should stay in the window..
Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/activity_kurs__chatroom"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="com.eitisoft.studentexchangecloud.Schulen.GymnasiumZwieselKlassen.GymnasiumZwieselQ11Kurse.Kurs_Chatroom"
   android:background="@drawable/test1">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_height="60dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText9"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:hint="Nachricht schreiben"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/buttonsend"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>


    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/listmessage"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout" />
```

I'm really at the end of my mind...
I've tried so much things but at least nothing helps..

Comment: add adjustpan in menifest activity tag